# Subject field in Contact form

Tags: input-fields, web, contact-us

Should the Subject field be required in a contact form? When I design a UI for a contact page on a web site, I have a form for emailing. I always have 3 fields on this page: Name, email, message. Some people say that it's a good idea to add a Subject field. Is this necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per user concern, users are now bored of filling forms, it's better keep less input fields.

Name, Email and Message fields are enough for moderator to understand from where this message came from.

Now a days, form inputs are very less, for example "Confirm Password" field input is now getting extinct, reason is clear user need less form element.

Answer (score 3):

Strongly agree with having few fields.

But, based on the subject, If actions are taken / filtered / grouped or sent to different sections / departments to handle, then YES, the subject field is very much required, otherwise, the segregation becomes very tough and time-consuming.

This will also help you get the statistical information and improve the UX of the page / screen if required.

Comment: Agreed. In other words, if you're not doing anything with the info submitted in the subject field, then don't use one. If it serves a purpose, then put one in there.

Answer (score 1):

The subject line is usefull for the receiver, but a burden for the sender.

- **Automated Subject line**: Fill it with info from other input fields: Name etc.

  - Advanced: Possibly you could spider the message? Subjects are often in the first line, and names below the message (assumption). Use that info to generate a subject line, helping the receiver filter their inbox.
- **Multiple choice**: "General
  Information", "Request for Support", "Contact me for an Appointment"
  etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think less input fields are not always the best solution.

If the form is just for one (general) type of emails, this may be simple for the user.

In the case you can provide some options for the subject, a select with some categories can be more comfortable for the user because he doesn't need to clarify this in the description too.

It can be something like:

"Interested in:

- design for my website;
- development"

or
"Tell us what you need help with:

- Information;
- Account, payment"